# Run arbitrary Java from AppEngine Dev Server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

To help with development, I want to launch some programs that require access to the file system, execution environment, etc, from the appengine development server.  Essentially, I want to write:

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value().equals(
        SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development)) {

    doStuffICannotDoOnRealAppengineButShouldBeABleToDoOnMyMachine();

}
```

Is this possible?

My goal is to preview email that AppEngine is sending.  Right now I can print the contents to System.out, but I'd like to save them to a file and launch a browser so my designers can see the email content immediately.

Comment: You could make your dev server access some other server using webservices... Not ideal but can solve your problem.

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain _why_ you want to do this?  There may be a better way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Good point, @Gray - I've added some context

Comment: Good idea, @Gilberto - I'll end up doing that if I can't find something better

Comment: Any feedback on my answer @RileyLark?

Answer (score 0):

Hrm.  I see a number of ways of accomplishing this *without* having to get around GAEs file system restrictions.

- You could provide some debug call with an email address request param which would send the particular email via [Google's email API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) to the address specified.  You'd probably want to see it "rendered" by the email client anyway.
- You could store the file using [Google's cloud storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/).  This should allow you to put a file that can be displayed via an URL.  If you can't using that API then you certainly can using S3's.
- You could make some HTTP post request to a local server using [Google's URL fetch API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary).  You could even do it to localhost port 8100 (or whatever) and then run netcat to receive the email `nc -l 8100`.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for a way to make the workflow seamless for our designers, though.  The email API doesn't work in dev mode.  The request to a local server might be the best bet; thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: No +1 for the response @Riley?